# Remove/Trim spaces from cells in excel sheet using vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to remove the leading and trailing spaces in an excel sheet. I have a code that is currently doing that but it is running through the entire sheet. I would like to select a range, instead of the whole sheet to save time.

I tried using a code already but i need to simplify to make the process faster.

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
v = r.Value
If v <> "" Then
If Not r.HasFormula Then
r.Value = Trim(v)
End If
End If
Next r
```

This code will remove spaces from the entire sheet.

Comment: Instead of using `UsedRange`, why not `Selection`? Or get the range from an input box.

Comment: **OR** Find the last row and the last column and then construct your range

Comment: If you really want to speed this up, you may want to capture your range as a variant array, make your adjustments to the array, then transpose the array back to your sheet.

Comment: If you don't mind using an add-in instead of coding this yourself, I can recommend https://www.asap-utilities.com/ It is an indispensable tool for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps:

```
Option Explicit
Sub trimConstants()
    Dim R As Range, C As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet2") 'better than using `ActiveSheet`
Set R = WS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

For Each C In R
    C = Trim(C)
Next C

End Sub
```